# Add Restriction Relation customer group with a function c#

Tags: acumatica

I would like add restriction group (CLTA) for the customer with c#.

[image]

What function I must use ?

```
var row = (Customer)e.Row;
if (row==null) return;
clt.GroupMask=....
```